# LearningShapelet with variable-length time-series returns nan in predictions array

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, classification, variable-length

I am working with variable-length time series. In particular, I am using the tslearn tool.
I transformed data so that they fit the allowed format for tslearn:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data, Y, test_size=0.3,random_state=42, stratify= Y)

X_train= to_time_series_dataset(X_train)
X_test= to_time_series_dataset(X_test)
```

then I run:

```
from tslearn.shapelets import LearningShapelets
clf = LearningShapelets(n_shapelets_per_size={3: 1})
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Everything runs smoothly, but when I run:

```
y_pred = clf.predict_proba(X_test)
```

I get

```
y_pred contains only 'nan' and no predictions.
```

Does anyone have a suggestion about why this is happening?